# Wowza Publish the live Stream on Apple HLS demand

Tags: ios, wowza, http-live-streaming

The problem is simple.  In Wowza when I use a stream file in live mode (so the streaming are published only when requested through RTMP), I'm not able to publish the streaming and get the video streaming when I use the JWPlayer on IOS (so through Apple HLS) so i'm looking for a method for streaming the cams-live on iOS on demand!

I've just started in Wowza so I cannot write Java code to expand the functionality for the moment so be patient.

I've seen this post on stackoverflow, but i can't see the solution, [Wowza: Need to stream rtp-live to iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410031/wowza-need-to-stream-rtp-live-to-iphone) !

Comment: Assuming you can see the streaming video on JWPlayer (via something like `rtmp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1935/live/myStream`), you should be able to see the streaming video on iOS via `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8`.

Comment: Yes, of course ! That 's right but if i've the streaming on Wowza set in live or liverepeter mode , so the streaming from the cam start only when the stream is requested from a viewer with the http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8 the stream do not start because only on RTMP / RTSP protocol the streaming on deman is able to start !! So here the problem ! Thnks